# Microsoft Office LaunchEvent OnMessageSend not working for windows outlook add-in

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am developing an add-in which uses OnMessageSend event (which is latest and recommended) in background, whenever email is sent a taskpane opens with message addin-error (**we can't start this add-in because it isn't setup properly**). This works fine in mac and web browser but facing this issue in windows outlook application. My project is based on react typescript.
outlook version=> Microsoft 365 MSO(Version 2305 Build 16.0.16501.20074) 32-bit.
Windows version=> Windows 10 Pro, 22H2.

Tried different combination on manifest but nothing works.

here is my mainfest.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Created:cb85b80c-f585-40ff-8bfc-12ff4d0e34a9-->
<OfficeApp
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
  xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides"
  xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>0102b412-be1d-4df3-b67d-819d84da5ae1</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.12</Version>
  <ProviderName>Dev addin</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Dev" />
  <Description DefaultValue="dev addin"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="" />
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://dev.cloud" />
  <AppDomains>
<AppDomain></AppDomain>
</AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="MailBox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <!-- These elements support older clients that don't support add-in commands -->
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <!-- NOTE: Just reusing the read taskpane page that is invoked by the button
             on the ribbon in clients that support add-in commands. You can
             use a completely different page if desired -->
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="http://example.com/taskpane.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>450</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemEdit">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="http://example.com/commands.html"/>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Edit" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>

  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">

    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
      
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />

          <!-- Message compose form -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgComposeDemoGroup">
                <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                
                <!-- Task pane button -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="paneComposeButtonLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="paneComposeSuperTipTitle" />
                    <Description resid="paneComposeSuperTipDescription" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                  <!-- icons 20, 24, 40, 48, and 64 pixels -->
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon-icon-16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon-icon-32" />
                    <bt:Image size="64" resid="icon-icon-64" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon-icon-80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="taskPaneUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>

          <!-- Message read form -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgReadDemoGroup">
                <Label resid="groupLabel" />

                <!-- Task pane button -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                    <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon-icon-16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon-icon-32" />
                    <bt:Image size="64" resid="icon-icon-64" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon-icon-80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="taskPaneUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>

        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>

    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <!-- icon icon -->
        <bt:Image id="icon-icon-16" DefaultValue="/icon-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon-icon-32" DefaultValue="/icon-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon-icon-64" DefaultValue="/icon-64.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon-icon-80" DefaultValue="/icon-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="http://example.com/commands.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="taskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="http://example.com/taskpane.html"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="dev"/>
        <!-- Compose mode -->
        <bt:String id="paneComposeButtonLabel" DefaultValue="dev"/>

        <bt:String id="paneComposeSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Enter your own text to insert"/>

        <!-- Read mode -->
        <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="dev"/>
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Opens dev addin"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <!-- Compose mode -->
        <bt:String id="paneComposeSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Opens dev addin"/>

        <!-- Read mode -->
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Opens dev addin"/>
        </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>

    <!-- VersionOverrides for the v1.1 schema -->
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">

      <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
          <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
        </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>
      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <Runtimes>
          <!-- HTML file including reference to or inline JavaScript event handlers.
               This is used by Outlook on the web and on the new Mac UI. -->
          <Runtime resid="WebViewRuntime.Url">
            <!-- JavaScript file containing event handlers. This is used by Outlook on Windows. -->
            <!-- <Override type="javascript" resid="JSRuntime.Url"/> -->
          </Runtime>
        </Runtimes>
          <DesktopFormFactor>
            <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />

            <!-- Message compose form -->
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                <Group id="msgComposeDemoGroup">
                  <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                 
                  <!-- Task pane button -->
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeOpenPaneButton">
                    <Label resid="paneComposeButtonLabel" />
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="paneComposeSuperTipTitle" />
                      <Description resid="paneComposeSuperTipDescription" />
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon-icon-16" />
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon-icon-32" />
                      <bt:Image size="64" resid="icon-icon-64" />
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon-icon-80" />
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="taskPaneUrl" />
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                </Group>
              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>

            <!-- Appointment compose form -->
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface">
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                <Group id="apptComposeDemoGroup">
                  <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                  
                  <!-- Task pane button -->
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="apptComposeOpenPaneButton">
                    <Label resid="paneComposeButtonLabel" />
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="paneComposeSuperTipTitle" />
                      <Description resid="paneComposeSuperTipDescription" />
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon-icon-16" />
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon-icon-32" />
                      <bt:Image size="64" resid="icon-icon-64" />
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon-icon-80" />
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="taskPaneUrl" />
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                </Group>
              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>

            <!-- Message read form -->
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                <Group id="msgReadDemoGroup">
                  <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                  
                  <!--test-->
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle"/>
                    <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon-icon-16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon-icon-32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="64" resid="icon-icon-64"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon-icon-80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="taskPaneUrl"/>
                    <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
             
                </Group>
              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>


          <!-- Enable launching the add-in on the included event. -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="LaunchEvent">
            <LaunchEvents>
              <LaunchEvent Type="OnMessageSend" FunctionName="onMessageSendHandler" SendMode="PromptUser" />
            </LaunchEvents>
            <!-- Identifies the runtime to be used (also referenced by the Runtime element). -->
            <SourceLocation resid="WebViewRuntime.Url"/>
          </ExtensionPoint>

          </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>

      <Resources>
        <bt:Images>
          <!-- icon icon -->
          <bt:Image id="icon-icon-16" DefaultValue="/icon-16.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="icon-icon-32" DefaultValue="/icon-32.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="icon-icon-64" DefaultValue="/icon-64.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="icon-icon-80" DefaultValue="/icon-80.png"/>
         
        </bt:Images>
        <bt:Urls>
          <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="http://example.com/commands.html"/>
          <bt:Url id="taskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="http://example.com/taskpane.html"/>
          <bt:Url id="WebViewRuntime.Url" DefaultValue="http://example.com/commands.html" />
        </bt:Urls>
        <bt:ShortStrings>
          <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="dev"/>
          <!-- Compose mode -->
          <bt:String id="paneComposeButtonLabel" DefaultValue="dev"/>

          <bt:String id="paneComposeSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Enter your own text to insert"/>

          <!-- Read mode -->
          <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="dev"/>
          <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Opens dev addin"/>

        <bt:String id="ActionButton.Label" DefaultValue="Perform an action"/>

        </bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:LongStrings>
          <!-- Compose mode -->
          <bt:String id="paneComposeSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Opens dev addin"/>

          <!-- Read mode -->
          <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Opens dev addin"/>
          <bt:String id="ActionButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Perform an action when clicked."/>

        </bt:LongStrings>
      </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

It seems like this code block is not executing from the xml:

```
<!-- Enable launching the add-in on the included event. -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="LaunchEvent">
            <LaunchEvents>
              <LaunchEvent Type="OnMessageSend" FunctionName="onMessageSendHandler" SendMode="PromptUser" />
            </LaunchEvents>
            <!-- Identifies the runtime to be used (also referenced by the Runtime element). -->
            <SourceLocation resid="WebViewRuntime.Url"/>
          </ExtensionPoint>
```

Comment: Does a newly generated add-in work correctly without using any third-party libraries?

Comment: See [LaunchEvent OnMessageSend not working for windows outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76476788/launchevent-onmessagesend-not-working-for-windows-outlook/76477571#76477571)